# How to modify Athena's primary workgroup configuration using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have created the following resources using Terraform:

1. `aws_athena_database`: Amazon Athena database
2. `aws_glue_catalog_table`: A CSV table for Athena

It is easy to change my my primary workgroup's default location for query results in the AWS console:[image: Athena console]

How can I achieve this using Terraform?

I have specified a custom `bucket` argument for the `aws_athena_database` to store my query results, which works well if I'm querying outside the Athena console (like Tableau), but if I'm working in the Athena console it [defaults](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html#default-location-query-results) to a generic Athena-provided S3 bucket.

Answer (score 4):

You want to us something like this in your terraform, however; this will produce an error because the workgroup already exists, so you will need to use terraform import in order to make terraform add this pre-existing resource to your state file:

```
terraform import aws_athena_workgroup.primary primary
```

```
resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "primary" {
  name       = "primary"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.my-results-bucket]
  configuration {
    enforce_workgroup_configuration    = false
    publish_cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true

    result_configuration {
      output_location = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.my-results-bucket.bucket}/"

      encryption_configuration {
        encryption_option = "SSE_S3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```